# Django Turn off/on pagination for one filter request

Tags: django, django-views, django-pagination

I have 2 models, 1 for Product and 1 for ProductImages with pagination set to 10. For any product, we can have associated multiple images.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    details = models.TextField(null = True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True, null=True)
```

```
class ProductImages(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='product_imgs')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product_imgs/', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.url
```

My ProductList view looks like,

```
class ProductList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.ProductListSerializer
    pagination_class = pagination.PageNumberPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            if 'category' in self.request.GET:
                category = self.request.GET['category']
                category = models.ProductCategory.objects.get(id=category)
                qs = qs.filter(category=category)
            if 'owner' in self.request.GET:
                print('get_queryset Owner')
                owner = self.request.GET['owner']
                qs = qs.filter(owner=owner)
                if 'available' in self.request.GET:
                    available = self.request.GET['available'] == 'true'
                    qs = qs.filter(available=available)
            ids = []
            for product in qs:
                # images = models.ProductImages.objects.filter(id=product.id)
                print('Images: %d', product.id)
                ids.append(product.id)
            for id in ids:
                print('Id %d', id)
            images = models.ProductImages.objects.filter(product__in=ids)
```

I am trying to fetch products and images associated with those products. When I fetch products I get 10 products (as per set pagination) and I get 10 images. But problem is I want to get all (say) 25 images associated with those 10 products, i.e. I want to turn off the pagination only for filter on ProductImages model. How can I achieve this?

I have tried looking up getting only one image per product but I couldn't find a solution for that either.